# How to run the same php script regardless of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, http

I was wondering how I would run my script `/greetings.php` on any page in the `/a` directory, even if that file didn't exist.

Currently in my `/a` directory I have no files. However, if someone visited my website like `www.example.com/a/john` it would print `hello` because it would have the `greetings.php` script run on it (even though there is no file in the `/a` directory called `john`). I am assuming maybe `.htaccess` has to do something with it, but I am not really sure.

greetings.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
```

Comment: One suggestion. Setup a 404 page and make it say whatever you want

Comment: Or simply implement a redirection rule pointing to that script. You will find endless examples for that here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly If set up a 404 error page, it would mean files in `/b`, or `/c` or `/` directory would also be affected by the 404 page rule? Even though I don't want them to be. I want them to experience normal 404 page errors, not the `greetings.php` script

Comment: Sounds a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385069/make-a-second-url-link-to-the-same-directory-as-a-different-url-without-copying/55397519#55397519 - where I gave a slightly different answer just a few days ago...)

Comment: @CFPSupport The answer for that doesn't answer my question at all. This is because `second-wiki.php` file has to exist for it to redirect to `wiki.php`. In my question there is no file called `second-wiki.php`. Completely different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?a/greetings.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?a/(.*)$ a/greetings.php [L,NC]
```

- We match all requests with a rewrite condition of `^/?a/(.*)$`. This matches all requests that have `/a` directory to access on your website.
- We then redirect it to your `greetings.php`. Note that we add an additional rewrite condition of `!^/?a/greetings.php` to prevent infinite internal redirections to the same script which Apache does. The `!` in the regex represents negation, meaning, match if and only if the regex request URI isn't matched, ultimately avoiding the infinite loop.

Comment: Does this change the URL though? For example if the user goes to `www.example.com/a/john` does the URL change to `www.example.com/greetings.php` or the URL is still `www.example.com/a/john`? I am trying to keep the URL still to be `www.example.com/a/john` **not** `www.example.com/greetings.php`. This way the user never knows that the `greetings.php` script is being run.

Comment: @Ross the URL doesn't change since there is no `R` flag. You can try this code on your server and let me know.